# Show or hide divs depending on user input

Tags: javascript, html, string, search, compare

I'd like to include a search function to my website so that the user can type some keywords in a search form and only some divs will show up. I'm not sure how to compare strings.
Here is my code:

```
<h1 class="title">News Journal</h1>

    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search for a subject...">

    <p class="mostViewed">Most visited news websites...</p>

    <div class="divCNN">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.cnn.com/"><img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/cnn-logo-2.jpg?w=892&h=598&crop=1" class="CNN"></a>
    <p class="description">CNN was founded in 1980 by American media proprietor Ted Turner as a 24-hour cable news channel. It was the first all-news television channel in the United States and CNN website has an average of 112 millions unique monthly visitors.<a target="_blank" href="https://www.cnn.com/"> Visit !</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="divNYT">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.nytimes.com/"><img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/t_logo_2048_black.png?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" class="NYT"></a>
    <p class="description">The New York Times is an American newspaper based in New York City with worldwide influence and readership. Founded in 1851, the paper has won 125 Pulitzer Prizes, and its website has 95 millions unique monthly visitors.<a target="_blank" href="https://www.nytimes.com/"> Visit !</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="divYNews">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.yahoo.com/news/"><img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/yahoo-news-logo.jpg?w=446&h=299&crop=1" class="YNews"></a>
    <p class="description">Yahoo! News is a news website that originated as an internet-based news aggregator by Yahoo!. Articles originally came from news services such as Reuters, Fox News, Al Jazeera, USA Today, CNN, BBC News, etc. 93 millions unique monthly visitors.<a target="_blank" href="https://www.yahoo.com/news/"> Visit !</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="divWPost">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.washingtonpost.com/"><img src="http://neatoday.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/washington-post-logo.jpg" class="WPost"></a>
    <p class="description">The Washington Post is a major American daily newspaper founded on December 6, 1877. It has a particular emphasis on national politics and its website has 92 millions unique monthly visitors.<a target="_blank" href="https://www.washingtonpost.com/"> Visit !</a></p>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Search() {

    }
    document.addEventListener("keyup", Search);
</script>
```

Like if the input is CNN, the function will .show() that particular div and no other.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `Here is my code: <empty function>` :/

Comment: Did it on purpose, I just don't know where to start :/

Comment: For a meaningful reply it would probably help to see more than just one site div in the HTML

Comment: elastic search rest api ;)

Comment: Just edited it !

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Ok I will, I felt like it was making it worse to post my script as it was very messy and way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try comparing against the `href` of each `a` inside the news divs (and give them a container for easy selection):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.search');
const newsDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#news-container > div');
input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  const str = input.value.toLowerCase().trim();
  newsDivs.forEach(newsDiv => {
    const href = newsDiv.children[0].href;
    newsDiv.style.display = 
      href.includes(str) ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<h1 class="title">News Journal</h1>

<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search for a subject...">

<p class="mostViewed">Most visited news websites...</p>


<div id="news-container">
  <div class="divCNN">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.cnn.com/"><img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/cnn-logo-2.jpg?w=892&h=598&crop=1" class="CNN"></a>
    <p class="description">CNN was founded in 1980 by American media proprietor Ted Turner as a 24-hour cable news channel. It was the first all-news television channel in the United States and CNN website has an average of 112 millions unique monthly visitors.<a target="_blank"
        href="https://www.cnn.com/"> Visit !</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="divNYT">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.nytimes.com/"><img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/t_logo_2048_black.png?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" class="NYT"></a>
    <p class="description">The New York Times is an American newspaper based in New York City with worldwide influence and readership. Founded in 1851, the paper has won 125 Pulitzer Prizes, and its website has 95 millions unique monthly visitors.<a target="_blank" href="https://www.nytimes.com/"> Visit !</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="divYNews">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.yahoo.com/news/"><img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/yahoo-news-logo.jpg?w=446&h=299&crop=1" class="YNews"></a>
    <p class="description">Yahoo! News is a news website that originated as an internet-based news aggregator by Yahoo!. Articles originally came from news services such as Reuters, Fox News, Al Jazeera, USA Today, CNN, BBC News, etc. 93 millions unique monthly visitors.
      <a
        target="_blank" href="https://www.yahoo.com/news/"> Visit !</a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="divWPost">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.washingtonpost.com/"><img src="http://neatoday.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/washington-post-logo.jpg" class="WPost"></a>
    <p class="description">The Washington Post is a major American daily newspaper founded on December 6, 1877. It has a particular emphasis on national politics and its website has 92 millions unique monthly visitors.<a target="_blank" href="https://www.washingtonpost.com/"> Visit !</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```